# Graph Isomorphism > What kind of Graph is this?

Tags: data-structure, graph

Essentially, this is a variation of [Comparing Two Tree Structures](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/54245/comparing-two-tree-structures), however I do not have "trees", but rather another type of graph.

I need to know what kind of Graph I have in order to figure out if there's a [Graph Isomorphism Special Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem#Solved_special_cases)...

[image: Pictures of Graphs]

As you can see, they are:

- Not Directed
- Not A Tree
- Cyclic
- Max 4 connections

But I still don't know the correct terminology, nor the which Isomorphism algorithm to pursue, guidance appreciated.

Comment: these are all Planar graphs

Comment: I've seen these occasionally called 'lattice subgraphs' or 'grid subgraphs' but that terminology doesn't seem to be as common as I was expecting.  In addition to being planar as Jimmy notes, they're also 'bounded-degree', and furthermore they're _bipartite_ (nodes can be colored Red and Green with each Red node connected only to Green nodes and vice versa).

Comment: One additional question: do you need 'true' isomorphism here, or do you want the lattice respected as well?  (e.g., should a 'straight line' of five links be considered isomorphic to a 'staircase' of alternating up/down and left/right links?)

Comment: @Jimmy - Planar! That's the ticket!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - Respecting the lattice would be too easy ;-)

Comment: Brute force solution: generate all minimum spanning trees, then test whether two spanning trees are the same. Ofc, run time would be horrible...